# How can I archive completed tickets in SharePoint's "Issue Tracking" app?

Tags: issue-tracking

I have created an Issue Tracking app on SharePoint for my organization. I would like to be able to move tickets marked as "Closed" to an archive / different location (or I would even settle for having them moved at a certain "age of ticket," or even moved manually). Basically, just trying to to keep the issue tracking dashboard clean and also not removing any data. I was somewhat lost in the settings, is there a way to do this easily?

Answer (score 0):

Probably better to change the list view to only show items where the status doesn't equal "closed", unless you have a reason for keeping the number of items in the list low.